# JavaScript Expense Tracker Calculator - Subtraction

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, calculation

Im trying to do a expense tracker with vanilla javascript that user can can add/remove their expense item and the Total of expense will be calculated accordingly.

I am using constructor to create object so later I can save in localStorage later and retrieve later (hv not done this part yet)

Here is the problem. There is no problem in adding atm but when it comes to removing item (if not remove in sequence), the calculation is messed up. E.g. Item 1, Item 2, Item 3. If I remove with order Item 3 --> Item2 --> Item No problem with total value of subtraction. But if start the removal from Item 1 or Item 2, the calculation will be messed up

Im not sure is it because there is no index/id in each item so calculation is not working. Appreciate for any help thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ExpenseTracker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <label name="expense">Expense: </label>
        <input id="inputField" name="expense" type="text">
        <label name="date">Date: </label>
        <input id="start" type="text" name="date">
        <label name="amount">Amount: </label>
        <input id="money" name="amount" type="number" min="0" step="0.1">
        <button id="add" >Add</button>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="listContainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="total">total</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <button onclick="clearHistory()">clear localStorage</button>
    </div>



    
    <script>
        class ExpenseObject{
        
        constructor(e, d, a){
          
          this.expenseDescription = e;
          this.dateObject = d;
          this.amount = a;
        }
      }
        function clearHistory(){
            localStorage.clear();
        }
        const createDate = flatpickr("#start",{
            dateFormat:"d-m-Y ",
        });

        let addButton = document.getElementById("add");
        let listContainer=document.getElementById("listContainer");
        let inputField= document.getElementById("inputField");
        let dateInput = document.getElementById("start");
        let amountField = document.getElementById("money");
        let total = document.getElementById("total");

        

        addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(!inputField.value || !dateInput.value || !amountField.value){
                alert("please do not leave blank in any field");
                return;
            }

            var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            var expense = document.createElement('td');
            var expenseDate = document.createElement('td');
            var expenseAmount = document.createElement('td');
            var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        
            
            deleteButton.innerHTML="X";

            let expenseStuff = new ExpenseObject (inputField.value,dateInput.value,amountField.value )
           
            expense.innerHTML = expenseStuff.expenseDescription; 
            expenseDate.innerHTML =  expenseStuff.dateObject;
            expenseAmount.innerText = expenseStuff.amount;
            listContainer.appendChild(newRow);
            newRow.appendChild(expense);
            newRow.appendChild(expenseDate);
            newRow.appendChild(expenseAmount);
            newRow.appendChild(deleteButton);
           
            
            inputField.value = "";
            amountField.value="";
            
            
            var totalAmount = parseFloat(total.innerText) || 0;
            totalAmount += parseFloat(expenseAmount.innerHTML);
            total.innerHTML = totalAmount;
           
            
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                newRow.removeChild(expense);
                newRow.removeChild(expenseDate);
                newRow.removeChild(expenseAmount);
                newRow.removeChild(deleteButton);
                totalAmount -= parseFloat(expenseAmount.innerHTML);
                total.innerHTML = totalAmount;
            })
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance it looks as though you are removing expenseAmount before you try to subtract its amount from the total. Are you not seeing an error in your browser dev tools console?

Comment: Hon, please check my solution when you have a chance. Thank you.

Comment: @AHaworth the console was fine, no error shows up. I think its because the calculation is still working but just not in the right way.

Comment: @BrandonMcConnell Thank you! you are right, it is because of scope level, it is working fine now! thank you so much for your help! appreciate it!

Comment: @honkwok Sure thing! Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue you were experiencing is that you declared `totalAmount` at the local scope, so each `deleteButton` event listner still references the old `totalAmount` value from when the listener was declared. If you declare that value in a higher-level scope, alongside `total`, everything works as expected.

Here it is in action:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ExpenseTracker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <label name="expense">Expense: </label>
        <input id="inputField" name="expense" type="text">
        <label name="date">Date: </label>
        <input id="start" type="text" name="date">
        <label name="amount">Amount: </label>
        <input id="money" name="amount" type="number" min="0" step="0.1">
        <button id="add" >Add</button>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="listContainer" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="total">total</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick="clearHistory()">clear localStorage</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        class ExpenseObject{
          constructor(e, d, a){
            this.expenseDescription = e;
            this.dateObject = d;
            this.amount = a;
          }
        }
        function clearHistory(){
            localStorage.clear();
        }
        const createDate = flatpickr("#start",{
            dateFormat:"d-m-Y ",
        });
        let addButton = document.getElementById("add");
        let listContainer = document.getElementById("listContainer");
        let inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");
        let dateInput = document.getElementById("start");
        let amountField = document.getElementById("money");
        let total = document.getElementById("total");
        let totalAmount = parseFloat(total.innerText) || 0;
        addButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(!inputField.value || !dateInput.value || !amountField.value){
                alert("please do not leave blank in any field");
                return;
            }
            const newRow = document.createElement('tr');
            const expense = document.createElement('td');
            const expenseDate = document.createElement('td');
            const expenseAmount = document.createElement('td');
            const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.innerHTML="X";
            let expenseStuff = new ExpenseObject (inputField.value,dateInput.value,amountField.value )
            expense.innerHTML = expenseStuff.expenseDescription;
            expenseDate.innerHTML =  expenseStuff.dateObject;
            expenseAmount.innerText = expenseStuff.amount;
            listContainer.appendChild(newRow);
            newRow.appendChild(expense);
            newRow.appendChild(expenseDate);
            newRow.appendChild(expenseAmount);
            newRow.appendChild(deleteButton);
            inputField.value = "";
            amountField.value = "";
            totalAmount += parseFloat(expenseAmount.innerHTML);
            total.innerHTML = totalAmount;
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                newRow.removeChild(expense);
                newRow.removeChild(expenseDate);
                newRow.removeChild(expenseAmount);
                newRow.removeChild(deleteButton);
                totalAmount -= parseFloat(expenseAmount.innerHTML);
                total.innerHTML = totalAmount;
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```